# PHP mt_random on a loop from WP ALL Import for Woocommerce , Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I am using WP All Import, and I use this code to do an exchange rate. I would like to do a discount randomly at the same time after converting it to my currency.

This is the code

```
function add_exchangerate($x) {
  $markup = 20;
  $y = $x * $markup;
  return $y;
}
```

What can I add to it to actually make it for example every 20th time it runs this function it will do a discount of maybe 13%?

was thinking on adding a

```
$i = 1;
$i++
$xnum = mt_rand(1,1000)
while ($x = $xnum) {
$z = $x/1.15
return $z
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use session to store a counter,rest of the logic is pretty simple

```
function add_exchangerate($x)
    {
    $_SESSION['calladd'] = isset($_SESSION['calladd']) ? $_SESSION['calladd'] + 1 : 0;
    if ($_SESSION['calladd'] == 20)
        {
        $discount = 13/100;
        $_SESSION['calladd'] = 0;
        }
    else
        {
        $discount = 1;
        }

    $markup = 20;
    $y = $x * $markup;
    return $y * $discount;
    }
```

Comment: I see, but I need to be random on the calladd, can I replace  == mt_rand(1,1000) with == 20??

Comment: @ingalcala I added 20 becasue I read it in the question,you can add whatever interval logic you want.

Comment: 20 is an exchange rate from USD to MXN. (for the record). let me give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: @ingalcala Post the new code in your question.Any error messages?

Comment: you know this is for WP ALL Import right? I am putting the code on a functions.php which has all my other working functions.

Comment: weird part is it does not do anything at all.

Comment: @ingalcala Do you have session_start() in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137836/discussion-between-ingalcala-and-mihai).